# Using an IF statement with a string using .value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Does the .value command return strings and if not how do you have an IF statement check if the cell(s) holds the correct string.

I am working on a budget sheet where a certain column sets which department the budget and its breakdown should be forwarded to.

```
Sub calcMonthly()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wssum As Worksheet

'set worksheets to copy values
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")
Set wssum = Sheets("Sheet 2")


Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Dim bumonth As Currency
Dim busum As Currency


'sort through Departments for % breakdown
For k = 0 To 18

    'sort through months
    For i = 0 To 11
    busum = 0
        'sort through each item
        For j = 0 To 350
            bumonth = 0
            bumonth = CCur(ws.Cells(3 + j, 37 + k).Value * ws.Cells(3 + j, 24 + i).Value)
            busum = busum + bumonth
        Next j
    'row C holds the string which details if the item if physical hardware or digital then uploads it to the cell
    If ws.Cells(3 + j, 3) = "SW" Then
        wssum.Cells(3 + k, 2 + i).Value = busum
    Else
        wssum.Cells(3 + k, 14 + i).Value = busum
    End If
    Next i
Next k


End Sub
```

Comment: Range.Value is variant, in other words, it returns a string when it is a string and a number if it is a number, without the number formatting.

Comment: but this `If ws.Cells(3 + j, 3) = "SW" Then` refers to `j` outside the j loop, `j` will always be `351` at that point.  I think you want `If ws.Cells(3 + k, 3) = "SW" Then`

Answer (score 0):

.Value does return a string, but it doesn't look like you included it in the IF statement.

If ws.Cells(3 + j, 3)**.value** = "SW" Then

Comment: `.Value` is default and as such does not need to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

`Range.Value` returns a `Variant` whose subtype depends on the content of the cell.

Given a `#N/A`, `#VALUE`, `#REF!`, or any other cell error value, it returns a `Variant/Error` that can't be coerced into anything other than a `Variant` - trying to compare it to a string or numeric value or expression will throw error 13 "type mismatch".

You can avoid this runtime error by evaluating whether the variant subtype is `Error` using the `IsError` function, ideally by capturing the cell's value into a local `Variant` variable first, so you don't have to access the cell twice.

Given an empty cell that has no formula, no value, no content whatsoever, it returns a `Variant/Empty`; the `IsEmpty` function can be used to validate this variant subtype.

Given a `Date` value, it returns a `Variant/Date`. Given any numeric value, it returns a `Variant/Double`. Given a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value, it returns a `Variant/Boolean`.

And given a `String` value, it does return a `Variant/String`.

---

Note that the *default member* of the `Range` class is a hidden `[_Default]` property with two optional parameters:

[image: Property _Default([RowIndex], [ColumnIndex]), default member of Excel.Range]

When no parameters are provided, an explicit call to `.Value` is equivalent. Explicit member calls should generally be preferred over implicit default member calls, and whether implicit or explicit, the calls should be consistent:

> ```
> If ws.Cells(3 + j, 3) = "SW" Then ' implicit: .Value
>     wssum.Cells(3 + k, 2 + i).Value = busum
> Else
>     wssum.Cells(3 + k, 14 + i).Value = busum
> End If
> ```